# stacked multi-value plots in Grafana with InfluxDB backend

Tags: plot, influxdb, stacked, grafana

I trying Grafana to visualize system data from InfluxDB 
I would like to use a multi-value selection to display the combined, stacked plots for differend values. In my example: the plot line of all jobs using 8 CPUs and the plot line of all jobs using 1 CPU stacked onto each other.

Thus, I created a variable for the tag in InfluxDB holding the number of CPUs:

```
 CPUs = SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "cpus"
```

This works well as long as I select/display only one case, as for 8 CPUs

[image: Grafana: multi-value variable selected as 8 only]

or as for 1 CPU

[image: Grafana: multi-value variable selected as 1 only]

However, if I select both cases, Grafana complains about a malformed query

[image]

with the error message

```
q   SELECT "value" *{1,8} FROM "jobs" WHERE "status" =~ /running$/ AND "vo" =~ /cms$/ AND "cpus" =~ /{1,8}$/ AND time > now() - 24h GROUP BY "vo", "cpus", "status" 

{
  "error": "error parsing query: found {, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 17",
  "message": "error parsing query: found {, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 17"
}
```

So, I wonder, why the (automatic) expansion of the 'CPU' variable as {1,8} do not work for the query towards InfluxDB?

Cheers,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU variable cannot be a multi value (have multiple values at the same time), {1,8} is not a math expression. Needs to be a single value .

Comment: ah, OK - but then, how can I realize such an intended plot with multiple sub-plots, i.e., expand multiple values into sub-plots? I tried wildcards etc. as well, but without success so far.